# Inserting Semi-Colons between Non-Blank Cells in a Range of Responses in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Just a quick question. I have a spreadsheet with a column of names and a row of multiple-response options (the animals below). I want to create a new column that displays responses with a semi-colon between all non-blank responses.

For example, if John has a snake and a cat, it would display as Snake;Cat. If John has a snake, cat and rabbit, it will display as Snake;Cat;Rabbit, but if John only has a snake, there will be no semi-colons, just Snake. So basically, no semi-colons before or after first or last responses, but only between respnoses when there are more than one.

How can this be easily achieved?

```
          Snake   Dog    Cat    Rabbit
```

John

Erin

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
Public Function Gather(rng As Range) As String
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In rng
        Gather = Gather & " " & r.Value
    Next r
    Gather = Replace(Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Gather), " ", ";")
End Function
```

[image]